# Advanced logging with NodeJs: { emitErrs } was removed in winston@3.0.0

Tags: node.js, logging

I have created this funcion to log into a file with verbosity level set to info, max 5 files and 5 MB for each 
and a complete full log (verbosity level debug) in the terminal but the different level should use different colors.

```
private initialize(): void {

        var winston = require('winston');
        winston.emitErrs = true;

        var logger = new winston.Logger({
            transports: [
                new winston.transports.File({
                    level: 'info',
                    filename: './logs/all-logs.log',
                    handleExceptions: true,
                    json: true,
                    maxsize: 5242880, //5MB
                    maxFiles: 5,
                    colorize: false
                }),
                new winston.transports.Console({
                    level: 'debug',
                    handleExceptions: true,
                    json: false,
                    colorize: true
                })
            ],
            exitOnError: false
        });

        module.exports = logger;
        module.exports.stream = {
            write: function(message : any, encoding : any){
                logger.info(message);
            }
        };

    }
```

but I have this error when starting the app.

Unexpected error occurred
Error: { emitErrs } was removed in winston@3.0.0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `emitErrs` option was removed in 3.0.0. Just remove it from your code. This line specifically:

```
winston.emitErrs = true;
```

See [this comment](https://github.com/winstonjs/winston/issues/1200#issuecomment-362183316) on GH